# Blazor wasm unable to resolve AuthorizationOptions while attempting to activate DefaultAuthorizationPolicyProvider

Tags: blazor, asp.net-authorization, blazor-client-side

I'm working on a Blazor wasm application and ran into an exception when adding the AuthorizeRouteView component in the App.razor file.  I lost quite some time trying to solve as there are few resources about this, so I want to share the solution here:

Error message was:

System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationOptions]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationPolicyProvider'.

Package versions:

```
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Build" Version="3.2.0-preview1.20073.1" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.DevServer" Version="3.2.0-preview1.20073.1" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.HttpClient" Version="3.2.0-preview1.20073.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization" Version="3.1.1" PrivateAssets="all"/>
```

Following descriptions I only had to add AddAuthorizationCore() in the Program.cs Services:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();
```

This then produces the above exception...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### The Solution

When I first added the AddOptions() to the Services in the Program.cs, the problem was solved:

```
builder.Services.AddOptions();
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a project which begun with Blazor 3.1 preview 4, and there was no need for this "AddOptions", it was all fine.
Then I´ve migrated it to Blazor 3.2.0 preview 1, did all the stuff recommended (no more startup, use program.cs only etc etc) and suddenly everything broke.
Those 2 lines from LYper´s answer solved my problem. Thanks.
Does anyone know why ???